# Setting up Database Schema for cloud based App

Tags: mysql, database, schema, cloud

I'm about to create my first cloud based app using PHP and MYSQL. I'm in a limbo and can't seem to figure out whether I should use one database which stores everything, or should I setup a dedicated database for each user that signs up to my service.

The application itself will be recording hundreds and thousands of records on daily basis. So having a one big shared database could get heavy. It could also lead to performance issues when querying the database. On the other hand, having a dedicated database for each user could potentially lead to maintenance problems (E.g backing up and keeping track of each database instance).

Could anyone please advise me on the best approach? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I think you'd have better luck asking on [/* Programmers */](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) or [Database Administrators](http://dba.stackexchange.com/). SO focuses on specific programming questions.

Comment: Did you make any progress on this?